# convert c# .NET Core console application into Lamba function

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, console-application

I have a .NET Core console application which runs inside windows task scheduler on schedule basis. now we want to move this C# to be hosted inside AWS. so we need to have this schedule function runs as Lambda function  .. so what are the changes that i need to make? and will it requires total rebuild of the console application?

Comment: Without giving us any hint of code or even what the application does, how could we know?

Comment: @Christopher yes you are right. the console application integrates with SharePoint online  using CSOM code by passing client id and client secret + it integrates with 3rd part tools using their REST API .. my question is if my console application code will work out of the box .. mainly the code inside the console application `static void Main(string[] args)` method?. thanks

Comment: You will need to setup a lambda project.  Just add one to your solution and migrate your main code to the function. Plenty of documentation on this from AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/developing-net-core-aws-lambda-functions/

Comment: @bhmahler ok thanks for the info.. so generally speaking what i can do inside C# console application can be done inside C# deployed inside AWS lambda function?

Comment: For the most part yes.  They do have a 15 minute execution time limit so any long running process will not work.

Comment: @bhmahler thanks for the reply,, but if i got your point correctly then unlike .NET console application .. we should not use lambda function for long running processes?

Comment: That is correct. Lambdas will timeout after 15 minutes.  They are designed to be called, run a quick function and end. Any long running process will need another approach.